# Generating Multiple Student Report Sheets in one web page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am building a student management app. Am stuck in viewing class reports. I can show individual reports (scores, percentage, personal details, psychomotor domain etc) for each student in a class. But I need to show all reports for each student in a class in one web page with page breaks between them. So we'll have Student1 with all scores and information, Student2 with all scores and information etc in on very long web page. My results table on DB has studentId and StudentClass columns to differentiate things. I feel I should use a forloop but can't wrap my head around how to.  Below is my controller:

```
public function viewclassresults(Request $request){



   $term = $request->get('term');
   if ($term ==1) {
       $termended = "First";
   }
   $session = $request->get('session');
   $sessionnow = Session::where('id', $session)->first()->name; 
   $classname = $request->classname;
   $class_id = $request->class_id;
   $teachersignature = Stclass::where('id', $class_id)->first()->teachersignature;
   $teachername = Stclass::find($class_id)->teachers()->first()->fullName;

   $setting = Setting::all()->first(); 

   $grades = DB::table('grades')->get();
   $comments = Comment::all();

      $results = DB::table('results')
                    ->where('studentClass', $class_id)->where('session', $session)->where('term', $term)->whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->selectRaw('results.*, (results.test1 + results.test2)/2 as cav, (results.exam + (results.test1 + results.test2)/2)/2 as totalmark, results.studentId as classstudents')->get();









       $rating = DB::table('ratings')->where('term', $term)->where('session', $session)->first();



        if($results->isEmpty()){

           return "No Result";
          // 
        } else{
            return view('teacher.results.viewclassresults', compact('subjects', 'studentname', 'regNumber', 'studentClass', 'studentId', 'term', 'session', 'results', 'student', 'setting', 'sessionnow', 'classname', 'termended', 'grades', 'comments', 'rating', 'teachername', 'resultpercent', 'resultpercentclass', 'teachersignature', 'classstudents'));
          // 
      }



}
```

It is  $results that actually show individual results. Please note that resultid (id) is the unique and primary key in my results table. below is part of my table:

[my results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUzJn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [constraint eager loading.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
$student = Student::with(['results'=> function($q1) use ($term, $studentId) {
    $q1->where('term', $term)
    ->where('studentId', $studentId)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->selectRaw('results.*, (results.test1 + results.test2) as cav, results.exam + results.test1 + results.test2 as totalmark');

},'ratings' => function($q2) use ($term, $session){
    $q2->where('term', $term)
    ->where('session', $session)
    ->first();
}])->get();

return view('view.template',compact('student'));
```

I see that you have many results. You could just add a method on your student model and eagerload the different type of results with it. I'm not sure what your relations are, but you essentially just keep chaining above.

The conditional statements in the controller is unneeded. You can do all of that in the view and deligate different partials.

The view would look close to something like this

```
@foreach($student as $student)
    @if($student->result->empty())
        <h1>No student result.</h1>
    @else
        @foreach($student->result as $result)
            //Get student result
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This code is untested. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kindly check my edit to the original question.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not getting back to you on this. Your suggested solution, while novel to me,due my shallow knowledge of Laravel, is looking good. However, I had to remove $studentId as it was undefined in my original code. However, I got "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when I ran the code. I noticed the problem was with the inner foreach. Could you check please? Thanks a zillion!